# Tkinter.Label not showing after button pressed

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, label

I'm trying to make, that after I press the button, I get the taken info shown in the label, however, I can't seem to make the label appear in the GUI. I get error, when I press "Vartotojo informacija > type in name and press "rodyti informacija" and I get error on this line `w.pack(LEFT)` (should be line 95-ish):

Full traceback:

```
'id' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "tkinter-label-not-showing-after-button-pressed.py", line 96, in <lambda>
    myg1 = Button(virsus, text="Rodyti informacija", command=lambda: gauti())
  File "tkinter-label-not-showing-after-button-pressed.py", line 103, in gauti
    w.pack(LEFT)
  File "C:\Python\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1946, in pack_configure
    + self._options(cnf, kw))
  File "C:\Python\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1169, in _options
    for k, v in cnf.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

My code:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox
from sys import version_info
import subprocess

root = Tk()
root.title("Administravimas")

virsus = Frame(root)
virsus.pack()
apacia = Frame(root)
apacia.pack(side=BOTTOM)

def filtras():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Filtravimas pagal uzklausa")
    root.geometry("300x100")
    tekstas = Text(root, height=1, width=15)
    tekstas.pack(side=TOP)
    virsus = Frame(root)
    virsus.pack()
    apacia = Frame(root)
    apacia.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    myg1 = Button(virsus, text="Filtruoti", command=lambda: gauti())
    myg1.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def gauti():
        imti=tekstas.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        subprocess.call("grep -i '{imti}' /var/log/syslog > "
                        "logai/uzklausa/$(date +%d_%m_%Y.txt)".format(imti=imti),
                        shell=True)

def vartotojas():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Filtravimas pagal vartotoju prisijungimus")
    root.geometry("300x100")
    tekstas = Text(root, height=1, width=15)
    tekstas.pack(side=TOP)
    virsus = Frame(root)
    virsus.pack()
    apacia = Frame(root)
    apacia.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    myg1 = Button(virsus, text="Filtruoti", command=lambda: gauti())
    myg1.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def gauti():
        imti = tekstas.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        subprocess.call("grep -i '{imti}' /var/log/auth.log > "
                        "logai/vartotojai/$(date +%d_%m_%Y.txt)".format(imti=imti),
                        shell=True)

def portas():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Atidaryti/uzdaryti portus")
    root.geometry("300x100")
    virsus = Frame(root)
    virsus.pack()
    apacia = Frame(root)
    apacia.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    myg1 = Button(virsus, text="Atidaryti porta")
    myg2 = Button(virsus, text="Uzdaryti porta")
    myg1.pack(side=LEFT)
    myg2.pack(side=LEFT)
    root.mainloop()

def administ():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Administrouti vartotojus")
    root.geometry("400x100")
    virsus = Frame(root)
    virsus.pack()
    apacia = Frame(root)
    apacia.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    myg1 = Button(virsus, text="Kurti vartotoja")
    myg1.pack(side=LEFT)
    myg2 = Button(virsus, text="Naikinti vartotoja")
    myg2.pack(side=LEFT)
    myg3 = Button(virsus, text="Keisti vartotojo grupe")
    myg3.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    root.mainloop()

def informacija():
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Vartotoju informacija")
    root.geometry("400x100")
    tekstas = Text(root, height=1, width=15)
    tekstas.pack(side=TOP)

    virsus = Frame(root)
    virsus.pack()
    apacia = Frame(root)
    apacia.pack(side=BOTTOM)
    myg1 = Button(virsus, text="Rodyti informacija", command=lambda: gauti())
    myg1.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    def gauti():
        imti = tekstas.get("1.0", "end-1c")
        info = subprocess.call("id '{imti}' ".format(imti=imti), shell=True)
        w = Label(root, text= "info")
        w.pack(LEFT)

    root.mainloop()

myg1 = Button(virsus, text="Filtruoti pagal uzklausa", command=filtras)
myg2 = Button(apacia, text="Filtrouti pagal vartotoju prisijungimus", command=vartotojas)
myg3 = Button(virsus, text="Atidaryti/uzdaryti portus", command=portas)
myg4 = Button(apacia, text="Administruoti vartotojus", command=administ)
myg5 = Button(apacia, text="Vartotojo informacija", command=informacija)


myg1.pack(side=LEFT)
myg2.pack(side=RIGHT)
myg3.pack(side=LEFT)
myg4.pack(side=RIGHT)
myg5.pack(side=RIGHT)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: some or all of your indentation is incorrect.

Comment: added full code, rest of it is unfinished, but I need help only with the 
`def informacija()` part

Comment: I can't reproduce the Attribute Error you say you got. Which button was pressed? Please [edit] your question again and add that information along with the full traceback up to the line on which the error occurred.

Comment: I've added what a full traceback is to your question. The problem is because you're trying to create multiple `root = Tk()` objects. Tkinter does won't work with them—there can only be one. Instead, you can create additional top-level windows using [`tk.Toplevel`](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/toplevel.html).

Comment: P.S. Off-topic: You can use `Button(virsus, text="Filtruoti", command=gauti)` instead creating a `lambda` as you do in statements like `Button(virsus, text="Filtruoti", command=lambda: gauti())`. Note there's **no** `()` following the `gauti`, so it won't be called while the `Button` is being constructed.

Answer (score 1):

For what I can see, the statement `w.pack(LEFT)` just needs a keyword (i.e. `w.pack(side=LEFT)`. Without keyword, it expects an argument of another kind (when calling `help(Button.pack)`, you'll see that this positional argument would be a dictionary)

Comment: thank you, that worked. However, now when I press the "rodyti informacija" button, the label gives me shows "0", when it's suppose to show the info about the user.

Comment: @Lenton; I don't really understand what you mean? And cannot reproduce your problem. You'd now like the Label `w` to show the info that was just entered in the text-box? Then specify so in the label; `w = Label(root, text = imti)`   (btw,  when requesting information, I think that normally the widget [`Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) would serve that duty better.)

Comment: I mean after I press the button, the shell command is ran with the variable from text box, everything works fine, except, I want the shell command result to be shown in label, but it shows "0" in label for me, however, in command prompt the shell command result is shown corectly.